# Font Rendering in Browsers

Tags: css, fonts

I am trying to use Impact Font in my website for heading and it reders like this in the browsers.

[image]

In Photoshop it looks like this

http://variable3.com/files/screenshots/2011-04-04_1612.png

CSS CODE

```
h1{
    font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, Arial Narrow Bold, sans-serif;
    font-size:30px;
}
h2{
    font-family: Impact;
    font-size:24px;
}
```

Comment: ... why does the browser not render the font 'properly'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm no mind reader, so I really have no idea what your question is, but you can't emulate Photoshop's font rendering engine using CSS.

Comment: aint Impact a Web Safe font ?

Comment: What does it being web-safe have to do with how Photoshop renders it, how your OS renders it, and how a browser renders it? Or did you mean to comment on the other two answers?

Comment: sorry i meant to comment on the other answer :(

Answer (score 1):

You have a crummy browser?

Either way, you  might find http://typekit.com/ interesting.

Comment: i am using ff4. and typekit doesnt have Impact in its Library :(

Comment: So, is it specific to FF4 or is it a problem in all browsers?

Comment: all browsers. it looks like the rendering problem. any idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use any of [Web Font Embedding Services](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/20/review-of-popular-web-font-embedding-services/).